# Help! Adding image to UIViewController Transition! :S

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I currently have several view controllers and transitions set up throughout my app using:

```
 ViewController2 *controller2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
 controller2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
 [self presentModalViewController:controller2 animated:YES];
 [controller2 release]; controller2 = nil;
```

What I really want is when the vertical transition is made, I want an image of bubbles to travel up the screen with the transition. Is there anyway of adding an Image to these transitions. If not I would like to know how to create this effect as I have seen it in apps before.

Thanks in Advance,

Adam

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding an Image to View Controller transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395124/adding-an-image-to-view-controller-transition)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to add a UIImageView the size of the view being animated, with your bubbles image set to it as a subview of that view. You can then remove it in the viewDidUnload or where appropriate in your code.